# Get all blocks including a specific substring?

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks

Is it possible to return all blocks which contain a specific substring?
e.g. return all blocks which contain the substring `slider_`.

I know I can return all blocks loaded in the current page like this:

```
$allBlocks = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getAllBlocks();
$blockNames = array_keys($allBlocks);

var_dump($blockNames);
```

But how can I get ALL blocks, even blocks not loaded at the moment, so I can filter the necessary ones with the target substring out?

Which way is recommended to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $blocks = Mage::getModel("cms/block")->getCollection();
    $searchString = 'slider_';
    foreach($blocks as $block) {
        if (strpos($block->getIdentifier(), $searchString) !== false) {
            echo $block->getIdentifier() . '</br>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm!